# PostgreSQL: get the min of a column with it's associated city

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been at this for the past two hours and have tried many different ways in regards to subquery and joins. Here's the exact question "Get  the  name  and  city  of  customers  who  live in the city  where  the least number  of products  are  made"

Here is a snapshot of the database tables

[image]

I know how to get the min

```
select min(quantity)
from products
```

but this returns just the min without the city attached to it so I can't search for the city in the customers table.

I have also tried group by and found it gave me 3 min's (one for each group of cities) which i believe may help me

```
select city,min(quantity)
from products
group by city
```

Putting everything together I got something that looks like

```
SELECT
     c.name,c.city
FROM
     customers c
INNER JOIN
     (
          SELECT
               city,
               MIN(quantity) AS min_quantity
          FROM
               products
          GROUP BY
               city
     ) AS SQ ON
     SQ.city = c.city
```

But this returns multiple customers, which isn't correct. I assume by looking at the database the city when the lowest number of products seems to be Newark and there are no customers who reside in Newark so I assume again this query would result in 0 hits.Thank you for your time.

Example 
Here is an example "Get the pids of products ordered  through  any  agent  who  makes  at  least one order for a customer in Kyoto"

and the answer I provided is

```
select pid
    from orders
    inner join agents
    on orders.aid = agents.aid
    inner join customers
    on customers.cid = orders.cid
    where customers.city = 'Kyoto'
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?  In other words, what do you want your query to do?

Comment: Hi Gordon I added an example for you at the bottom. I would like this query to get the name and city of customers who live in the city where the least number of products are made. I assume this question is talking about the quantity column in the products table. Also take a look at the database table layout in the link I provided. It will clear everything up

Comment: It'd be good to have sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and not as a picture.

Comment: I'll be sure to use sqlfiddle in future questions, did not know about it until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured out my own answer. I guess taking a break and coming back to it was all I needed. For future readers this answer will use a subquery to help you get the min of a column and compare a different column (of that same row) to a different tables column.

This example is getting the city where the least number of products are made (quantity column) in the products table and comparing that city to the cities to the city column in the customers table, then printing the names and the city of those customers. (to help clarify, use the link in the original question to look at the structure of the database I am talking about) First step is to sum all the products to their respective cities, and then take the min of that, and then find the customers in that city.Here was my solution

```
with citySum as(
select city,sum(quantity) as sum
from products
group by city)

select name,city
from customers
where city 
in
(select city
from citySum
where sum =(
select min(sum)
from citySum))
```

Here is another solution I have found today that works as well using only Sub queries

```
select c.name,c.city
from customers c
where c.city 
in
(select city 
from
(select p.city,sum(p.quantity) as lowestSum
from products p
group by p.city) summedCityQuantities
order by lowestsum asc
limit 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postgresql you have sophisticated tools, viz., windowing and CTEs.

```
WITH 
  find_least_sumq AS
  (SELECT city, RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY city ORDER BY SUM(quantity) ) AS r 
   FROM products)
SELECT name, city 
FROM customers NATURAL JOIN find_least_sumq /* ON city */ 
WHERE r=1; /* rank 1 is smallest summed quantity including ties */
```

In Drew's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898953/717898), you are zeronig in on the cities where the smallest number of any particular item is made. I interpret the question as wanting the sum of items made in that city.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in the fact the cities have to be summed first since there are multiple cities with the same name. Then grouped and then the min taken from that. I did not understand this at the time so thanks for making this clear to everyone. As I am sure your answer is sufficient, I have also made this one (see my edited answer), which I believe is also correct. Thank you for your time, I will have go to learn what partition, over,and natural join do!

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is just a shortcut for a `JOIN` on columns with the same name. You can live without it, at the cost of more typing. Windowing functions are one of the best things since sliced bread (hmm, use of American phrase maybe not best on site like this). They let you write shorter queries for certain types of questions, that probably run better too. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess it be something around this idea:

```
select customers.name, city.city, city.min
from customers 
join (
  select city, sum (quantity) as min
  from products 
  group by city
  --filter by the cities where the total_quantity = min_quantity
  having sum (quantity) = (
             --get the minimum quantity
             select min(quantity) from products
             )
     ) city on customers.city = city.city
```

Comment: Hey just figured out the solution to my own problem. I did try yours though and it seemed to work, but I could not tell for sure. I tried testing it to find the max quantity so I can actually see the output and see that it is correct, but could not get that working. In my own solution I was able to test it and confidentially say that that solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This can be made so much simpler. Just sort the output by the field you want to get the minimum of.

```
SELECT city, quantity FROM customers ORDER BY quantity LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi, I believe that this would work if there wasn't multiple cities with the same name and different amount of products. If I am thinking correctly, we would need to sum all the products that belong to their respective cities, and then take the min of that and find out which city truly has the lowest, then find the customers with that city